# EC2 used space increases after resizing volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, expand, amazon-ebs

I have followed [AWS guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html) to expand the 8GB volume to 16GB.

What I have done is:

1. Take snapshot of 8GB volume
2. Create new 16GB volume by the snapshot
3. Detach 8GB volume from EC2 instance, then attach 16GB volume to that EC2 instance

After that, `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       16G   11G  5.3G  67% /
```

Why the `Used` size increase to 11G? It should be 8G.

Comment: There is no intrinsic reason why this would happen.

Comment: seems the resize is successful, are there any new logs generated to fill the space quickly?

Comment: @BMW: I checked `/var/log`, nothing strange.

Answer (score 0):

While the disk is 'bigger', the partition has not yet been extended to cover the new disk space.

Use `sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1` to extend the disk partition to include the additional space on the disk.

See: [Extending a Linux File System](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html#recognize-expanded-volume-linux) on that same page.

Comment: Not succeeded. `lsblk` shows that partition `xvda1` is 16G. So, it should be something else.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein You might want to take a second look at the question.  The *filesystem* reports 11GB of 16GB used.